# DocuSign API - Create Envelope with Redirect URL

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API to create envelopes and have DocuSign send the email to the recipients to begin the signing process. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to include some kind of redirect URL that DocuSign will redirect signers to when they have finished signing the document.

I'm looking through the [EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs) resource but haven't seen anything that allows me to specify a URL here, so not sure if this is even possible at all with Remote Signing? We are not using the embedded singing option and don't have any plans to at the moment so just looking to see if this is possible via Remote Signing at this stage.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can do this, but not via the API. Instead, you set the URLs at the account level via the `Brand`:

1. Open the eSignature Admin tool
2. Navigate to Account / Brands
3. Click on the brand you want to change.
4. At the bottom of the screen, Click on **Destination URLs**
5. Set the URL for when the recipient has completed signing.

If some of your account's envelopes should redirect to your application server, and others should not (sent manually?), then you'll need more than one brand for your account. (One brand will have the redirect settings, the other will not.)

Then, when your app sends an envelope via the API, set the `brandId` and `brandLock` attributes in the `envelopeDefinition` object.

Note that the `Brand` feature is not included with all types of DocuSign accounts. Consult your DocuSign Account Mgr for more info.